# MemoryError on row-wise outer products in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, out-of-memory, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have two matrices. I make row-wise outer products between them. My original aim was to increase speed performance. I have the working code on samples but when I want to do them with (+2000, +2000) shape matrices I got `MemoryError`.

I tried to convert them into sparse, but this is not possible for 3D or with `einsum` (See for instance [this comment](https://obilaniu6266h16.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/einstein-summation-in-numpy/#comment-81)).

Is there a way to solve this?

Here are the sample matrices:

```
A
Out[10]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])

B
Out[11]: 
array([[0.25, 0.  , 0.5 , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.25, 0.  , 0.5 , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.25, 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  ],
       [0.25, 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ]])
```

And here is an example of doing the product:

```
A[:, :, None] * B.T[:, None, :]
Out[12]: 
array([[[0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
        [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
        [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
        [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25]],

       [[0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.5 ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.5 , 0.5 ]],

       [[0.5 , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.5 , 0.5 , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]],

       [[1.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]],

       [[0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 1.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]],

       [[0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 1.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]],

       [[0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 1.  ]]])
```

I also tried to make the product with the following ways, with the same result:

```
np.einsum('ij, ik -> ikj', A, B.T)
```

and

```
np.matmul(A[:, :, None], B.T[:, None, :])
```

Comment: So with the example, you create a (7,4,7) array.  What's the target size with the large arrays?  If the target size is too big, it doesn't matter what evaluation method you use.  `einsum` (and `matmul`) are really intended for matrix product (inner product), though as you found you can use them for outer product.  But broadcast based outer should be just as good.

Comment: `scipy.sparse` uses 2d matrices.  While its matrix product is well developed, it does not implement any sort of broadcasting, or extension to 3d.  `einsum` isn't needed when the 2 inputs, as well as the output are 2d.  There few possible combinations  'ij,jk->ik', 'ij,kj->ki' etc. are easily handled with matrix product and transpose.  Sparse also needs sparsity of around 1% to gain much advantage in speed and memory use.

Comment: Thanks, @hpaulj. The new array, of course, would be very big (+2000, +2000, +2000). I used `einsum` and `matmul` to reduce running time (which they do, compared to for loops). The broadcast and outer combination I did not try, I will check it out.